# Why is cls.__dict__[meth] different than getattr(cls, meth) for classmethods/staticmethods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class-method, descriptor

I've never seen anything else work like this before.

Is there anything else that does this?

```
>>> class NothingSpecial:
     @classmethod
     def meth(cls): pass

>>> NothingSpecial.meth
<bound method classobj.meth of <class __main__.NothingSpecial at 0x02C68C70>>
>>> NothingSpecial.__dict__['meth']
<classmethod object at 0x03F15FD0>

>>> getattr(NothingSpecial, 'meth')
<bound method NothingSpecial.meth of <class '__main__.NothingSpecial'>>

>>> object.__getattribute__(NothingSpecial, 'meth')
<classmethod object at 0x03FAFE90>

>>> type.__getattribute__(NothingSpecial, 'meth')
<bound method NothingSpecial.meth of <class '__main__.NothingSpecial'>>
```

Comment: Because classmethods are descriptors.  Read up on descriptors.

Comment: So I see that the pure python implementation of class method located on the descriptor how-to does the same thing. So I guess that means that `type.__getattribute__` is doing something special if it gets a descriptor. But I still can't figure out how to emulate that behavior.

Comment: `type` is a metaclass, the default metaclass for all classes. It probably *is* doing something special.

Comment: @bup: If you want to emulate it, you should ask a separate question about that (and maybe explain why you want to do that).

Answer (score 2):

### Getattr Uses Descriptor Logic

The main difference is that the dictionary lookup does no extra processing while the attribute fetch incorporates extra logic (see my [Descriptor How-To Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) for all the details).

### There Are Two Different Underlying Methods

1) The call `NothingSpecial.__dict__['meth']` uses the square brackets operator which dispatches to `dict.__getitem__` which does a simple hash table lookup or raises *KeyError* if not found.

2) The call `NothingSpecial.meth` uses the dot operator which dispatches to `type.__getattribute__` which does a simple lookup followed by a special case for [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-descriptor).  If the lookup fails, an *AttributeError* is raised.

### How It Works

The overall logic is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=descriptor#implementing-descriptors) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=descriptor#invoking-descriptors).

> In general, a descriptor is an object attribute with “binding
>   behavior”, one whose attribute access has been overridden by methods
>   in the descriptor protocol: __get__(), __set__(), and/or __delete__(). If
>   any of those methods are defined for an object, it is said to be a
>   descriptor.
>
> The default behavior for attribute access is to get, set, or delete
>   the attribute from an object’s dictionary. For instance, a.x has a
>   lookup chain starting with a.__dict__['x'], then
>   type(a).__dict__['x'], and continuing through the base classes of
>   type(a) excluding metaclasses.
>
> However, if the looked-up value is an object defining one of the
>   descriptor methods, then Python may override the default behavior and
>   invoke the descriptor method instead. Where this occurs in the
>   precedence chain depends on which descriptor methods were defined and
>   how they were called

Hope you've found all of this to be helpful.  The kind of exploring you're doing is a great way to learn about Python :-)

P.S.  You might also enjoy reading the original Whatsnew in Python 2.2 [entry for descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.2.html#descriptors) or looking at [PEP 252](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0252/) where Guido van Rossum originally proposed the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
object.__getattribute__(NothingSpecial, 'meth')
```

and

```
NothingSpecial.__dict__['meth']
```

return the same object in this case. You can quickly check it by doing:

```
NothingSpecial.__dict__['meth'] is object.__getattribute__(NothingSpecial, 'meth')

$True
```

Both of them points to the same [descriptor object](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)

on the other hand:

```
object.__getattribute__(NothingSpecial, 'meth') is getattr(NothingSpecial, 'meth')

$False
```

Basically, they aren't they are not the same object nand the same type:

```
type(object.__getattribute__(NothingSpecial, 'meth'))
$<class 'classmethod'>

type(getattr(NothingSpecial, 'meth'))
$<class 'method'>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is that `getattr` will automagically invoke an object's `__get__` method if it has one, whereas `object.__getattribute__` and the objects `__dict__` lookup do not. The following function proves that:

```
class Nothing:

    @classmethod
    def a(cls): 
        return cls()

    @staticmethod
    def b(): 
        return 'b'

    def c(self): 
        return 'c'

def gitter(obj, name):
    value = object.__getattribute__(obj, name)
    if hasattr(value, '__get__'):
        if isclass(obj):
            instance, cls = None, obj
        else:
            instance, cls = obj, type(obj)
        return value.__get__(instance, cls)
    return value

>>> gitter(Nothing, 'a')()
<__main__.Nothing object at 0x03E97930>
>>> gitter(Nothing, 'b')()
'b'
>>> gitter(Nothing(), 'c')()
'c'
```

However, `gitter(Nothing(), 'b')` doesn't work currently because it's not detecting that the `objtype` default value is `None`, but this is enough.

Comment: `object.__getattribute__` will perform descriptor handling, but the descriptor handling will be *regular object* descriptor handling, not class object descriptor handling; for regular objects, descriptors in the object `__dict__` don't get descriptor methods invoked.